# Bounded vector field in a square region (soft question)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a system of integral curves how does one find the associated system of differential equations and the vector field corresponding to these integral curves?

Comment: In what form are you given that system of integral curves?

Comment: a family of parametric curves

Comment: Just take the partial derivative w.r.t. the parameter.